# How to read and save booleans from a repository with DataStore in Jetpack Compose

Tags: checkbox, android-jetpack-compose, repository, data-class, android-jetpack-datastore

I have a repository including a list of words which I connected with a unique checkbox. Each time I close the app I want the checkbox value to be saved. So I am using Jetpack DataStore for that.
It saves properly but it does it for all the words and I wish it does it for each of them separately.

I know how to retrieve that when they are String but can't figure out when they are Boolean.

My Repository

```
object WordRepo {

    fun getWord(wordId: String, context: Context): Words =
        getWordsList(context).find { it.wordId == wordId }!!

    fun getWordsList(context: Context) = listOf(

        Words(
            wordId = context.getString(R.string.a),
            wordName = context.getString(R.string.a),
            wordCheckBox = false
        ),

        Words(
            wordId = context.getString(R.string.cold),
            wordName = context.getString(R.string.cold),
            wordDone = false

        ),

        Words(
            wordId = context.getString(R.string.star),
            wordName = context.getString(R.string.star),
            wordCheckBox = false

        ),
)
}
```

My CheckBox

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val dataStore = DataStore(context)
var checkBool by remember { mutableStateOf(value = word.wordCheckBox) }



    Checkbox(
        checked = checkBool,
        onCheckedChange = {
            checkBool = it
            scope.launch { dataStore.saveBool(word.wordCheckBox) }
        }
    )
}
```

My DataStore

```
    
class DataStore(private val context: Context){

    companion object {
        val Context.dataStore:
                DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "MyPreferences")

        val BOOL = booleanPreferencesKey("checked")


    }

    val getBool: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data.map {
            preferences -> preferences[BOOL]?: false }

    suspend fun saveBool(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences-> preferences[BOOL] = value }
    }
}
```

Comment: the provided code doesn't provide the real problem, but from what you explained it sounds like you are asigning a single **Boolean** variable to all of your words and thats wrong instead **you want a boolean for each word**,  and to do that jetpack Datastore is not what you want to use instead you have to use some form of database like **Room DB** for exemple.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, dear Ayman. I am going to have a look at Room DB.